# Why is there a correspondence between $ |\text{Proj}\;S| - V(f) $ and $ \text{Spec}\; (S_{f})_{0}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Forgive me for the length of this post, but I feel this question is deserving of some detail.

Suppose $ S $ is a positively graded $ A$-algebra, where $ A $ is a ring. That is $ S = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} S_{i}, $ where $ S_{i} \cdot S_{j} \subset S_{i+j}. $

$f $ is a homogeneous element of $ S $ of degree 1, that is, $ f \in S_{1},$  and $ V(f) $ denotes the set of elements of $ \text{Proj}\;S $ which do not contain $ f $.

I am reading Eisenbud & Harris' "Geometry of Schemes". In Exercise III-6(a), the authors make the following statement:

> The intersection $ (I \cdot S[f^{-1}]) \cap S[f^{-1}]_{0}) $ is generated by elements obtained by choosing a set of homogeneous generators of $ I $ and multiplying them by the appropriate negative powers of $ f.$

I think I understand this statement intuitively. But they go on to infer the correspondence from here, and proceed give the following hint concerning the manner of constructing the maps:

> The correspondence is given by taking a prime $ \mathfrak{p} $ of $ S[f^{-1}] $ to $ \mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{p} \cap S[f^{-1}]_{0} $ and taking the prime $ \mathfrak{q} $ of $ S[f^{-1}] _{0} $ to $ \mathfrak{q}S[f^{-1}].$

My difficulty boils down to not knowing how to use this hint to establish the result explicitly/mechanically.

Comment: I will refer you to [Lemma 10.56.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JM) of the Stacks project.

Comment: @jgon Thanks for the heads-up, especially since this lemma is a generalisation of my question. I am following the argument. But I have hit a snag. I'm not sure why the following is true: "If $ \mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} \in \mathfrak{p}_{0}S, $ with  $ \mathfrak{a} $ and $ \mathfrak{b} $ homogeneous, then $ a^{d}b^{d}/f^{\text{deg}(\mathfrak{a}) + \text{deg}(\mathfrak{b})} \in \mathfrak{p}_{0}.$"        What am I missing? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately I'm about to sleep, but if your difficulty is unresolved when I wake up in the morning, I will answer the question then

Comment: @jgon No problem. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: @jgon I still can't see it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't read that last night, since I was on the app, which doesn't tex comments. I'm not sure why you're using fraktur $a$ and $b$, since they're not in fraktur in the lemma, which is important because they aren't ideals, they are homogeneous elements of the ring. Then notice that $a^db^d/f^{\deg(a)+\deg(b)}$ has total degree $0$, and is a multiple of $ab$, so it is in $\mathfrak{p}_0S\cap S_0$, which by the first sentence is $\mathfrak{p}_0$.

Comment: @jgon Yes, sorry I should not have used fraktur, and when I noticed the error, it was too late. I gathered that $ a^{d}b^{d}/f^{\text{deg}(a)+\text{deg}(b)} $ must have degree $ 0 $ by virtue of the conclusion. I'm just not sure why that is.

Comment: I see. We use the fact that $\deg f = d$ and $\deg \alpha\beta = \deg \alpha + \deg \beta$ (for homogeneous elements(!)). Then $\deg (a^db^d/f^{\deg a + \deg b}) = d\deg a + d\deg b - (\deg a+\deg b)\deg f = 0$.

Comment: @jgon I feel so stupid right now. Thanks for your help